# Multiple Decorator function calls wtih Decorator Design Pattern

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, decorator

I have a conceptual question for the Decorator pattern

Suppose we have the following decorator pattern:

```
class abs{
public:
  int c; 
  virtual void imp() =0;

}

class Base: public abs{
public:
  void imp() override;
}

class Decorator: public abs{
protected: 
  abs *a;
public:
  void imp() override { return a->imp(); }
}

class A:public Decorator{
public:
  A(abs *a): Decorator{a}{}
  void imp() override;
}

class B:public Decorator{
public:
  B(abs *a): Decorator{a}{}
  void imp() override;
}

class C:public Decorator{
public:
  C(abs *a): Decorator{a}{}
  void imp() override;
}
```

Inside each `imp()` the integer `c` is changing over and over again. For this example lets say that 1 is being added to it for A, 2 for B and 3 for C

Now we create a pointer to the base class

```
abs *a = new Base;
```

Then we decorate a in any arbitrary order with A/B/C lets say BACA
Example:

```
a = new B{a};
a = new A{a};
a = new C{a};
a = new A{a};
```

And in the end we call `a->imp();`

Does this mean that `c` now has the last value that was assigned to it by the imp() in class A i.e c+1?

What should we do if we want to initiate `imp()` for the entire order i.e c+2+1+3+1 but only call `imp()` once at the end

Assume initial c to be 0

Implementation of imp() in A for example:

```
void A::imp(){
  c = c+1;
}
```

I am really sorry if my question seems vague I will keep updating it based on the responses

Comment: A [mre] of what you're trying to explain might help

Comment: This is the smallest possible example I could think of, I removed all implementation and wrote a simplified skeleton of my code

Comment: What are the implementations of `imp`? What is `ump`? where is `c` set/used?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry that was a typo, I have edited the question

Comment: @ChrisDodd I changed it all to `a` to adhere to the minimal reproducible examples principle

Comment: If I ever come across something of this nature in practice, I'm thinking that my first order of business should be not to figure out exactly what version of Buzzword Bingo this is. This wouldn't seem to be productive; rather, I would look to rip it out by its roots, and redesign the whole thing from the ground up.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am practicing with different design patters, I just want to make sure I understand the behaviour in certain conditions

Comment: For a decorator, *every* subclass of Decorator's imp function should call Decorator::imp (explicitly).  You're basically building a linked list of decorators that will all get called (recursively) when you call the "top" one.

Comment: Somehow, I manage to do just fine in C++ without having memorized every "design pattern". C++ is complicated enough already, the formal specification run to almost two thousand pages of terse text. That's enough for me, for now, and I'm going to put off reading up on all the buzzword bingo until next week.

Comment: Where is `c` changing?

Comment: @MadPhysicist whenever `imp()` is called

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of the comments (especially @Chris Dodd) I was able to come up with an answer.

Q.Does this mean that c now has the last value that was assigned to it by the imp() in class A i.e c+1?

A.Yes, since our variable `a` is now of the type `A` it will call the function associated with class A

Q.What should we do if we want to initiate imp() for the entire order i.e c+2+1+3+1 but only call imp() once at the end?

A.Add `Decorator::imp();` to the end of each function and it will recursively call the functions.
Note: Depending on you implementation `c` might not get updated so you might want to pass it as a variable and return it to the final spot.

Comment: Note that every decorator will have its own `c` independent of whatever it is decorating (and its `c`).  Decorators mostly only make sense when you have a pure interface base (no data members) that you are decorating.

Comment: I encountered that too and the default `c` kept getting decorated rather than the one i wanted whenever the decorator::imp() was called. I guess passing c slightly breaks the decorator pattern but it gets it to work

Comment: If you move `c` to `Base` rather than `abs` (and perhaps add `getc()` to `abs`) then it might make more sense.  Then each decorator will not create a new `c`.